# Mongodb c# Unit testing: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

I'm trying to unit test a data repository for my Workorders.

The repository takes a DatabaseContext instance which accesses the mongodb database and exposes the IMongoCollection for the workorders as you will see posted below.

I use Moq to make mocks of both the IMongoCollection and DatabaseContext.
In the Moq setup for the DatabaseContext i choose to return the IMongoCollection when the exposed Workorder property is called. And in turn, the mocked IMongoCollection returns a DeleteResult.Acknowledged(1) task when DeleteOneAsync 
 is called.

In this way i hoped for some unit testing without needing the database running, but i got stuck with an error telling me "`System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`", pointing at a row when i am trying to do "`return result.DeleteCount == 1`, in which result is the returned DeleteResult object.

It seems like my result isn't created properly, below is my code.

**The error itself**
*Occurred when running the tests*

```
Test Name:  MESAPITests.RepositoryTests.WorkorderRepositoryTests.DeleteWorkorderById_ReturnsBooleanTrue
Test FullName: MESAPITests.RepositoryTests.WorkorderRepositoryTests.DeleteWorkorderById_ReturnsBooleanTrue
Test Source:    C:\Users\Zacke\Documents\Repositories\MES-API\MES-API Tests\RepositoryTests\WorkorderRepositoryTests.cs : line 22
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.354

Result StackTrace:  
at MESAPI.Repositories.WorkorderRepository.<DeleteWorkorderById>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Zacke\Documents\Repositories\MES-API\MES-API\Repositories\WorkRepositories\WorkorderRepository.cs:line 28
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MESAPITests.RepositoryTests.WorkorderRepositoryTests.<DeleteWorkorderById_ReturnsBooleanTrue>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Zacke\Documents\Repositories\MES-API\MES-API Tests\RepositoryTests\WorkorderRepositoryTests.cs:line 34
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Result Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**DataRepositoryTests**

```
public class WorkorderRepositoryTests
{
    private WorkorderRepository _repo;

    [Fact]
    public async void DeleteWorkorderById_ReturnsBooleanTrue()
    {
        var mockCollection = new Mock<IMongoCollection<Workorder>>();
        mockCollection
            .Setup(_ => _.DeleteOneAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Workorder, bool>>>(),
                default(CancellationToken)))
            .ReturnsAsync(await Task.Run<DeleteResult>(() => new DeleteResult.Acknowledged(1)));

        var mockContext = new Mock<IDatabaseContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(_ => _.Workorders).Returns(mockCollection.Object);

        _repo = new WorkorderRepository(mockContext.Object);
        var id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
        var result = await _repo.DeleteWorkorderById(id);
        Assert.True(result);
    }
}
```

**WorkorderRepository**
*Error occurred on second line in DeleteWorkorderById*

```
public class WorkorderRepository : IWorkorderRepository
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<Workorder> _workorders;

    public WorkorderRepository(IDatabaseContext context)
    {
        _workorders = context.Workorders;
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteWorkorderById(string id)
    {
        var result = await _workorders.DeleteOneAsync(w => w.Id == id);
        return result.DeletedCount == 1;
    }

    public async Task<List<Workorder>> GetAllWorkordersAsList()
    {
        return await _workorders.FindAsync(new BsonDocument()).Result.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<Workorder> GetWorkorderById(string id)
    {
        return await _workorders.FindAsync(w => w.Id == id).Result.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task<Workorder> PostNewWorkroder(WorkorderPost workorderPost)
    {
        var newWorkorder = new Workorder(workorderPost);
        await _workorders.InsertOneAsync(newWorkorder);
        return await _workorders.FindAsync(w => w.Id == newWorkorder.Id).Result.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task<bool> UpdateWorkorder(Workorder workorder)
    {
        var result = await _workorders.ReplaceOneAsync(w => w.Id == workorder.Id, workorder);
        return result.MatchedCount != 0;
    }
}
```

**IDatabaseRepository**

```
public interface IDatabaseContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Mongo database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoDatabase Database { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// BomFamily database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<BomFamily> BomFamilies { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// BomGroup database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<BomGroup> BomGroups { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// BomItem database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<BomItem> BomItems { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<Event> Events { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// EventAttribute database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<EventAttribute> EventAttributes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// EventType database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<EventType> EventTypes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Job database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Product database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// QualityEvent database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<QualityEvent> QualityEvents { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// QualityTest database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<QualityTest> QualityTests { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// QualityVariable database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<QualityVariable> QualityVariables { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Status database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<Status> Statuses { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// StatusGroup database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<StatusGroup> StatusGroups { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// User database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// WorkArea database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<WorkArea> WorkAreas { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// WorkCell database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<WorkCell> WorkCells { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Workorder database context.
    /// </summary>
    IMongoCollection<Workorder> Workorders { get; set; }
}
```

**New error when changing input type on DeleteOneAsync**
*To* `It.IsAny<FilterDefinition<Workorder>>()`

```
Test Name:  MESAPITests.RepositoryTests.WorkorderRepositoryTests.DeleteWorkorderById_ReturnsBooleanTrue
Test FullName:  MESAPITests.RepositoryTests.WorkorderRepositoryTests.DeleteWorkorderById_ReturnsBooleanTrue
Test Source: C:\Users\Zacke\Documents\Repositories\MES-API\MES-API     Tests\RepositoryTests\WorkorderRepositoryTests.cs : line 21
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.283

Result StackTrace:  
at MESAPI.Repositories.WorkorderRepository.<DeleteWorkorderById>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Zacke\Documents\Repositories\MES-API\MES-API\Repositories\WorkRepositories\WorkorderRepository.cs:line 28
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MESAPITests.RepositoryTests.WorkorderRepositoryTests.<DeleteWorkorderById_ReturnsBooleanTrue>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Zacke\Documents\Repositories\MES-API\MES-API Tests\RepositoryTests\WorkorderRepositoryTests.cs:line 33
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Result Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

[Picture: Hovering over result in the line above tells me it's null for some reason..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk5cp.png)

Comment: The issue here may be that the overload of `DeleteOneAsync` you are using (viz `Expression<Func<Workorder, bool>>` is a static extension method, i.e. not actually on the `IMongoCollection` interface at all, so the setup isn't invoked. You might need to use an on-interface overload of `DeleteOneAsync` [like this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_DeleteOneAsync_1.htm), or wrap Mongo in your own interface abstraction if you need to Unit Test it. You should also change `void DeleteWorkorderById_ReturnsBooleanTrue` to a return `Task`

Comment: @StuartLC : I used "FilterDefinition<Workorder>" instead of the Expression in the example above before, but that gave me the same error.

And true about the return type, will change that.

Comment: @ZackariasMontell You are also mixing blocking calls `.Result` with async await in `WorkorderRepository`, which can lead to deadlocks.

Comment: @StuartLC, My fault, it actually resulted in another simular stacktrace. 
I've added it at the end of my question.

Comment: @Nkosi Would this lead to a deadlock when testing if it works fine in normal use i.e. Http requests via swagger or postman to controller which uses this repository?

Answer (score 1):

Update based on comments. *Credit to StuartLC*

Moq is unable to mock extension methods and should be done directly on members of the interface being mocked.

[`IMongoCollection<TDocument>.DeleteOneAsync Method (FilterDefinition<TDocument>, CancellationToken)` Method](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_DeleteOneAsync_1.htm)

```
mockCollection
    .Setup(_ => _.DeleteOneAsync(It.IsAny<FilterDefinition<Workorder>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(new DeleteResult.Acknowledged(1));
```

Comment: I've tried that before i added the first row you wrote.
It yields the same result as far as errors goes.

Comment: As a comment to your edit. Isn't that what i've already done?

I changed the CancellationToken from `default(CancellationToken)` to `It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()` but that doesn't change the outcome for me at all :/.

Maybe i don't fully understand what you are saying..